Poor primer adhesion to drywall topping roll on coat
Room-by-room, I've been tackling a 25 year old house in Hawaii that has horrible paint adhesion. The first room I did was an attached studio with ~1000 sqft of wall space, and this was my process;

Peeled off all the old paint to expose the drywall
Lightly sanded (electric pole sander) and wiped down the surface
Sealed with Zinsser Gardz (2 coats)
Rolled on a slightly thinned layer USG read-mix topping compound to give a roll coat effective (1-2 coats with 1/2" nap)
Sealed/primed with Zinsser Gardz
Top coated with Sherwin Williams

It worked like a charm and and the top coat looks and is adhering great. However, when I went to try this in the next room I ran out of Gardz after step 3. Gardz is NOT easily found on this island and not always available to order. After months of trying to find it I had to use Zinsser 123 for step 5 (priming). When I was rolling it on I noticed it was starting to "interact" with the topping coat (almost making bubbles in it). The topping coat also feels very brittle like you could sand it all down with your bare hand.
The end result after one coat of Zinsser 123 is horrible paint adhesion (way worse that what I was trying to fix). I have no idea what went wrong this time, whether I waited to long between the topping coat and the primer (had surgery and also couldnt find Gardz and had to wait a few months), or whether the topping was bad or thinned too much.
Anyways, I am so mentally and emotionally defeated and just don't know what to do next. Do I just keep swimming and put the second coat of Zinsser 123 primer on and hope it doesn't flake off? Re-drywall the entire room? Wood paneling? I don't have the strength of spirit to peel all the paint off again. I'm also unconvinced that something like Zinnser Peel Stop would fix the problem, but maybe I'm wrong.
Any input appreciated....I'm depressed and going to go walk my dog.....
Video of tape test;
https://youtu.be/Tlph96cn5r4

What were you trying to fix with the topping coat? Gardz is a penetrating seal. 123 is a surface seal. The adhesion problem is the topping coat on the existing surface. Is that what is coming off?
